# Constructing an Equilateral Triangle Inscribed Inside a Circle

Tags: graphics, geometry

How to plot something like this? I need only the triangle and the 3 circles green. Thank you! [image]

Comment: It is expected that you show your own efforts. The minimum that you could have done is coordinates of the points A, B and C as well as the radius of the green circle. Surely you do not expect us to do it for you.

Comment: Without making extensive guesses, it's impossible to determine what you're really asking.  What would your input be?  Centers and radii of the circles?  The points A ... F? Something else?  What, if anything, are you assuming about the shape of the triangle or the relative sizes and positions of the circles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another one liner:

```
Graphics[{{Yellow, #}, {Green, Circle /@ #[[1]]}}] &@
  SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Nice! Yours has one less variable to set by hand than mine, too, since you get to use unit-radius circles. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, perhaps more direct:

```
pts = CirclePoints[3]
Graphics[{
  Thick, Green, Circle[#, Sqrt[3]] & /@ pts,
  Yellow, EdgeForm[Black],
  FilledCurve@Line@pts
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

There's probably an easier way to do this, and there is probably a more informative way to do it - more illuminating for those who are new to *Mathematica*.  But this way was more fun for me to come up with, using primarily `RegionIntersection` to find the points.

```
circles = {Circle[{-1/2, 0}, 1], Circle[{1/2, 0}, 1]};
AppendTo[circles, 
  Circle[RegionIntersection[circles] // First // Last, 1]];
triangle = (RegionIntersection[#1, #2, Disk @@ #3] &) @@@ 
           (RotateRight[circles, #] & /@ Range[3]) // Part[#, All, 1] & // Polygon;
Graphics[{Green, circles, Yellow, EdgeForm[Black], triangle}]
```

[image]

Or, if you are using an older version of *Mathematica* then you have to get the intersection points yourself,

```
Graphics[{Green, {Circle[{-(1/2), 0}, 1], Circle[{1/2, 0}, 1], 
   Circle[{0, Sqrt[3]/2}, 1]}, Yellow, EdgeForm[Black], 
  Polygon[{{1/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}}]}]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you <3

Comment: There is some error in the code?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtVjRG7PB_4&feature=youtu.be&t=9s

Comment: @AndreaLeo - not that I'm aware, if it doesn't work for you, you need to be more specific, what version are you using, what error message do you get?

Comment: During evaluation of In[136]:= RegionIntersection::reg: Circle[1,1] is not a correctly specified region. >>
During evaluation of In[136]:= RegionIntersection::reg: Circle[1,1] is not a correctly specified region. >>
During evaluation of In[136]:= RegionIntersection::reg: Disk[1,1] is not a correctly specified region. >>
During evaluation of In[136]:= General::stop: Further output of RegionIntersection::reg will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
3/23/16 13:57:42 
1 is not a valid coordinate
3/23/16 13:57:42 
Coordinate Circle[1, 1] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica 10.0

Comment: @AndreaLeo - see the edit.  Out of curiosity, do you know how you would algebraically find the points for the circle centers that make up the triangle?

Answer (score 3):

The new in M12 function [`GeometricScene`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricScene) could be useful for you:

```
scene = GeometricScene[
    {a, b, c}, (* points *)
    {
    Triangle[{a, b, c}],
    CircleThrough[{a, b}, c],
    CircleThrough[{b, c}, a],
    CircleThrough[{c, a}, b]
    }
];
scene //RandomInstance
```

[image]

You can then use [`FindGeometricConjectures`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeometricConjectures) to find conjectures that hold for the scene:

```
FindGeometricConjectures[scene]["Conclusions"]
```

> {GeometricAssertion[Polygon[{b, a, c}], "Regular"], 
>    Inactive[PlanarAngle][{a, b, c}] == Inactive[PlanarAngle][{b, a, c}] == 
>     Inactive[PlanarAngle][{b, c, a}] == 60 [Degree]}

So, the triangle is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: You can also style @CarlWoll's elements to match the original color specs. This doesn't affect FindGeometricConjectures at all.  Note that synthetic geometry in MMA is in an experimental release; a simple scene like this will run without issues, though.

`scene =
  GeometricScene[
   (*Vertices*)
    {a, b, c},
   (*Hypotheses*)
   {
    Style[Triangle[{a, b, c}], Yellow],
    Style[CircleThrough[{a, b, c}], Red],
    Style[CircleThrough[{a, b}, c], Green],
    Style[CircleThrough[{b, c}, a], Green],
    Style[CircleThrough[{c, a}, b], Green]
  }];
scene // RandomInstance`

Comment: ^^ Sorry for lack of proper code formatting in that last comment.  I haven't figured out how to do that in mini-markdown in a comment yet (if it can be done).